# In an arbitrary polygon, how do I detect freedom from intersection of any side by another?

Tags: geometry, pathgeometry

I am drawing a polygon for the Traveling Salesman problem, and would like to test for non-intersection of any paths, as a means of adaptively halting the genetic search. I tried simply checking line segments or intersection, but sometimes I get an incorrect result, terminating the search even though one or more intersections remain.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is essentially equivalent to detecting intersections in an arbitrary set of line-segments.

For example, the [bentley-ottmann algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm) can be used to solve this problem. Of course, you can terminate as soon as you find one intersection.

A naive check would just check every edge versus every other edge (that is not adjacent in the polygon, because those cannot intersect), but since you just need to find *one* intersection, the output-sensitive algorithms (like bentley-ottmann) can speed up your check quite a lot.